# Making a simple program to verify copied folders

Tags: c++, copy, verify

First self-directed programming project.
C++. Windows 7.
Trying to verify folder copied successfully, along with all sub-folders and files.

Pseudo-code so far looks like this:

```
//First create a window to interact with
//  two 'browse' fields for folder/file locations, one 'compare' button to execute

//use window to choose folders to compare

//get a list of subfolders and files
//  maybe a list of file paths?

//go file-by-file and compare
//  compare file paths? ignore folder name changes?

//COMPARE FILES
//  COMPARE SIZE BY FINDING END OF FILE
//      IF NOT SAME POSITION, DIFF. FILE, RETURN
//  IF SAME SIZE, CONTINUE
//      read your files into large buffers of memory and compare each buffer using memcmp() you will improve performance
//      break up into 1-10-50 megabytes, use memcmp on those chunks
//      loop until end is reached
```

First: is the concept sound? find folders, get list of items in folders, compare items many times, break as soon as one difference is found, return location. Comparing files is the only thing I have any idea on how to actually implement, the rest will require further learning.

Second: should I even be trying to make a basic window, or should I just get the basic idea working in my IDE first?

Comment: Can you open up a command window and issue commands to compare the folders?

Comment: I recommend obtaining a utility that already has this feature, such as BeyondCompare, or `diff`.  Don't waste your time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Regarding your “second” question: Definitely separate the logic for comparing directory trees from your user interface.

Comment: Personally, I'd not implement this in code, especially if I was tied to a platform. I'd use the robust copy calls for the OS (robocopy or rsync) which will verify based on a checksum

Comment: "First self-directed programming project."